# Dual Turtlebot Arms

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm, manipulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have two of the Turtlebot arms installed on their Turtlebot? Is there any reason this wouldn't be possible/advisable?

Thanks

Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44156/dual-turtlebot-arms/) by [andyroojp](https://answers.ros.org/users/2590/andyroojp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could do this, you would have to adjust a number of configuration files, the urdf, etc. I would suggest using a single ArbotiX and then making the second arm have higher servo IDs so that no IDs are duplicated between the arms.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1